# How to create a trigger to modify date column on table with double key 

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, audit

I need to create a trigger that saves the current date&timestamp into the row when it is being inserted or updated.

Table structure

```
[Period] [char](7) NOT NULL,
[CompanyAlfaCode] [char](2) NOT NULL,
[SamplePercentaje] [int] NULL,
[Usuario] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Date] [Datetime] NULL,
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I have tried CREATE TRIGGER DateTrigger
 ON CompanySampleConfig
 AFTER UPDATE
 AS
 -- Prevent recursion!
 BEGIN
 SET Date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 END

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DateTrigger ON CompanySampleConfig
AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE CompanySampleConfig SET [Date] = current_timestamp
  WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT '' FROM inserted
  WHERE CompanySampleConfig.[Period] = inserted.[Period]
    AND CompanySampleConfig.[CompanyAlfaCode] = inserted.[CompanyAlfaCode]
END
```

Comment: Period and CompanyAlfaCode are both keys

Comment: Ok, I edited to put in Period and CompanyAlfaCode as a composite primary key.